# Python Kivy: How to check if a button is clicked or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have to create multiple buttons (for each element in a given list). For this I'm using for loops. The button that is pressed, must be recorded. However, the value of self.i is not stored at that particular instance, the last value (in this case - 2 is stored, after the loop is completed). How can I solve this error? Is there a way to add conditional statements to check if the button is clicked or not, and if it is, the value of self.i is stored in another variable.

```
class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InfoPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.peers = ["ishika", "nate", "nf"]
        for self.i in range(3):

            self.peers[self.i] = Button(text=peers[self.i], id=str(self.i))
            self.add_widget(self.peers[self.i])
            self.peers[self.i].bind(on_press=self.add)

    def add(self, _):
        id_of_button_pressed = self.peers[self.i].id
        print(id_of_button_pressed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `add()` method is using `self.i`, which will be the last value that `self.i` was set to in the `__init__()` method (`2`). So you just need to modify your `add()` method to something like:

```
def add(self, button):
    id_of_button_pressed = button.id
    print(id_of_button_pressed)
```